# Run a conditional bash command inside of tox

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, tox

I'm trying to run conditional bash commands in Tox.

If the user passes 'stag' into the script, tox should run one curl command; if they pass 'prod' into the script, it should run another curl command.

```
[testenv]
ENV=$1
whitelist_externals=
    /bin/bash
deps=
    -rrequirements.txt
commands=
    bash -ec 'curl https://this_is_just_sample_test.com'
    pytest test/test.py
```

When I try introducing a condition to the batch command:

```
[testenv]
ENV=$1
whitelist_externals=
    /bin/bash
deps=
    -rrequirements.txt
commands=
    bash -ec 'if [$1 == "stag"]; then curl https://this_is_just_sample_test.com fi'
    pytest test/test.py
```

I get the following error message:

> ERROR: InvocationError for command '/bin/bash -ec if [$1 = "stag"];
>   then curl https://this_is_just_sample_test.com fi' (exited with code
>   2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me fix the code for you (I added spaces for `[]` command, changed parameter to `$0` and added a semicolon):

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals=
    /bin/bash
deps=
    -rrequirements.txt
commands=
    bash -ec 'if [ "$0" == "stag" ]; then curl https://this_is_just_sample_test.com; fi' {posargs}
    pytest test/test.py
```

[`{posargs}` is a substitution](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-positional-arguments-in-commands) that allows to pass command line parameters from `tox` invocation. Like this:

```
$ tox stag
```

Comment: `allowlist_externals` is a new name for `whitelist_externals`. It is only a more politically correct synonym.